# API call over jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I'm trying to build a .js file that sends data to an external API, waits for a response and interprets the results. The external API is XML-based and accepts an HTTPS Post with the XML as body (content-type; text/xml). I can call the API correctly via cURL.

This is what I have so far:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="CallService()">

<script type="text/javascript">
var webServiceURL = 'https://www.url.com';
var xmlString = '<xml><parameter1>value1</parameter1>
<parameter2>value2</parameter2></xml>';

function CallService() {
   $.ajax({
      url: webServiceURL, 
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "xml", 
      data: xmlString, 
      processData: false,
      contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
      success: OnSuccess, 
      error: OnError
});
  return false;
}

function OnSuccess(data, status) {
  alert(data.d);
}

function OnError(request, status, error) {
  alert('error');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery.support.cors = true;
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I open the HTML I get an alert saying "error" and nothing appears on the other end (the external API's). Is there a way to do this using just JavaScript/Ajax/jQuery or do I need a "supporting" code that receives the JS call?

Comment: There are all sorts of issues making calls from a browser to URLs on a different domain. The basic answer is that it's not possible, though some recent developments have made it possible to have a server allow such requests. You must have control of the server software to do that.

Comment: What if I did had control of the server.. what kind of settings would I have to alter to allow this?

Comment: Look for tutorials on "CORS" - Cross-Origin Resource Sharing. It's an HTML5 thing, and it involves some special headers and things like that. Of course older browsers don't support it, but it's 2012 after all :-)

Comment: @user1375193 use header Access-Control-Allow-Origin: wwww.your-scripts-domain.com (documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control). Its nothing to do with html5, works everywhere

Answer (score 0):

When you want to make cross domain queries, you have basically 3 types of solution :

1) use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), which won't interest you if you're using XML and not JSON

2) not really do cross-domain, by setting a kind of proxy (or any type of get) on the server serving the main html page

3) changing headers on the server to specify to the browser that you accept cross-domain queries. This is new but yet accepted by all major browsers. That's called [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control). It's easy to change the headers ("Access-control-...") in all server-side languages so that should now be the preferred way (if you have issues (security, rights, bandwidth, ad, etc.) with cross-domain access to the data you serve, you can restrain the allowed origins).